# When does a $D$-module think it’s a pullback along a smooth morphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, d-modules, perverse-sheaves

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two algebraic varieties, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism. Suppose $A$ is a holonomic $D$-module on $Y$. In this situation we can pull $A$ back to $X$ using either the $!$ or $*$ pullbacks. If $f$ was smooth, then the two operations would agree for all sheaves up to a shift.

What if $f$ isn’t smooth? Are there still conditions we can put on $A$ to guarantee that the two pullbacks agree (up to a shift)? I am particularly interested in the case when $f$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: Maybe it's true when $f$ is transverse to the characteristic cycle of $A$.

Comment: @WillSawin could you say anything more about the intuition behind your guess?

Comment: If $Y = X \times Z$ and the inclusion $X\to Y$ is by a point in $Z$, then this is true if $A$ is pulled back from $Z$, and also in that case the transversality holds. Also I know some similar properties generalize from smooth morphisms to the characteristic-cycle-transversal condition.